# Read names/phone numbers from text file and store them into an array in java

Tags: java, arrays, object, java.util.scanner

The problem wants me to complete the code by reading the first four names of the text file and storing it into the array.

Here is the code to fill in.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class PersonDemo
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    File file = new File("phonedata.txt");
    Scanner infile = new Scanner(System.in);
    Person[] pArray = new Person[4];
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
      String n = infile.nextLine();
      String p = infile.nextLine();
```

What am i supposed to be inserting in here?

```
     }  
     infile.close();

   }
}
```

The object file being used is:

```
public class Person
{
  private String name = "";
  private String phone ="";

public Person(String n, String p)
{
    name = n;
    phone = p;
}

public  Person()
{
    name ="";
    phone="";
}
public void setName(String n)
{
    name =n;
}
public void setPhone(String p)
{
    phone = p;
}
public String getName()
{
    return name;
}
public String getPhone()
{
    return phone;
}
public String toString()
{
    return "Name: "+name + "  Phone: " + phone;
}

}
```

The text file being used is:

> Olivia
>
> 555-1111
>
> Tim
>
> 555-2222
>
> Theresa
>
> 555-3333
>
> Forest
>
> 555-4444
>
> Frank
>
> 555-5555
>
> Simon
>
> 555-6666

Now how am I supposed to use the object file to store the text into the array I am confused on what the code is supposed to look like?

Comment: what version of java you are using?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Why do you use `new Scanner(System.in);` ? You'll be reading the standard input of the application, not the file you would like to read. Try looking into the FileReader and BufferedReader. 
I'm also a bit confused about why you're using a Scanner for this purpose (the Javadoc reads: A simple text scanner which can parse primitive types and strings using regular expressions.).

Comment: it's for class my teacher gave the sample code and we were supposed to fill it in.

Comment: Your teacher is probably trying to fool you, might tell him that it won't work because the Scanner is using the wrong input. I suppose the white lines between the name and the phone number are caused by copy-pasting ? If these white lines are supposed to be there then the code won't work either (because you first read a name and then you read an empty line).

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow `@tristan`

After `String p = infile.nextline();`, do `pArray[i] = n + " " + p`

This should make your loop look like:

```
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
  String n = infile.nextLine();
  String p = infile.nextLine();
  Person person = new Person(n, p); 
  pArray[i] = person;
}
```

This should do what you are asking for.

Comment: This wouldn't compile because `pArray` is of *type* `Person` and not `String`.

Comment: How do i print out the result?

Comment: @NicholasK absolutely right. i was being absent minded and made the mistake

Comment: @tristanhoward i hv updated the answer. now if you want to print it, you can do `for(Person p:person){p.toString();}`

Comment: it says the for each is not applicable it requires an array.

Comment: try it with `for(int i=0;i<4;i++){System.out.println(pArray[i].toString());}`. If it still doesn't work, please tell, and I will check running the code myself

Comment: You could also use Arrays.toString(Object[]) -> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(java.lang.Object[]) . It will do exactly what you want: iterate over the array and call toString() on each object. You'll have to add it outside your for-loop, otherwise it'll try to iterate over the complete array which will contain 1 Person and 3 null's which will cause a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this logic :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
   String name = infile.nextLine();
   infile.nextLine();               // skip a line because there is a blank line in between
   String phoneNum = infile.nextLine();
   infile.nextLine();               // here again skipping a blank line
   Person per = new Person(name, phoneNum); 
   pArray[i] = per;
}
```

Explanation :

1. Here we store the *name* and *phone number* in string variables `name`
   and `phoneNum`.
2. Now using these variables we create an *object* of Person using the
   parameterized constructor.
3. Next, we assign this object to the corresponding index of the array.

Also your scanner should be defined as below to read the file via your scanner object `infile`

```
Scanner infile = new Scanner(file);
```